# Stronger type for `value` in `JSON.stringify(value: any)`

Tags: json, typescript

The official TypeScript lib [type definition](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/8af8f3c4d1e5cc6654916de9f42e9ba370513157/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1144-L1150) for the `value` argument to `JSON.stringify(value)` is `any`.

Is there a stricter type for `value` such that serializing and deserializing it would result the same value? In other words, such that the following were true:

```
deepEqual(value, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
```

For example, if `value` were a `Date` object, the above statement would be false.

The answer I'm looking for is

```
type SerializableValue = ...
```

Comment: @Mushroomator It does not. This question is asking for a stronger type definition of `value` such that `value === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))`.

Comment: No there is not, otherwise you'd find it in the type definition. Also `value === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))
` can only ever be true for primitive values, never for objects, since the object instances would be different. What you are probably looking for is `deepEqual(value, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))`. For details on how to get some type safety look at the linked thread.

Comment: You're right about `deepEqual`, that was a slip on my part, thanks

Comment: Appreciate the link on type safety... I'm still after a more well-constrained type argument though. This type is for a library function where I'd like to provide a better parameter type to users such that, for example, `Date` is NOT allowed. The official type definition is `any` because many things _can_ be passed to `stringify` including dates, but not in a lossless way (e.g., `Date`, `BigInt`, `Infinity`). There's definitely a stronger type when adding the requirement that `JSON.parse()` should result in the same value.

Comment: Ok, now I see, what you are aiming for. Retracting my close vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
type JSONSerializeable = 
| boolean
| number
| string
| null
| JSONSerializeable[]
| Record<string, JSONSerializeable>
```

Technically there are more things JSON can serialize, but the above is what it can *deseriaize*

You may use

```
export { }
declare global {
  interface JSON {
    parse(text: string): JSONSerializeable
  }
}

let x = JSON.parse('{"foo":"bar"}')
//  ^?
// let x: JSONSerializeable
```

in a `my-global-types.d.ts` in your project to declare it globally

Comment: Thank you. This is probably as close as we can get. This is actually still a superset of what is deserializable since `NaN` and `Infinity` have type `number` but do not pass the `value === JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value))` test

Comment: @Shruggie you can deserialize `Infinity` from `1e999` but you can't serialize it back

Comment: @Shruggie technically `NaN` couldn't pass the test anyways as `NaN !== NaN`

Comment: Yeah fair enough! I'll accept this answer, but just a nit that you might get a circular reference error on `JSONSerializable`. The `JSONValue` defined in this comment https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-331765301 is ultimately the same idea.

Comment: Thanks. Going to accept this answer since I believe it's as close as one can get with types.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Dimava's answer and this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1897#issuecomment-331765301), `type JSONValue` is the closest it gets:

```
type JSONValue = string | number | boolean | null | JSONObject | JSONArray;

// Helpers
type JSONObject = { [member: string]: JSONValue };
interface JSONArray extends Array<JSONValue> {}
```

But, there are still some limitations:

```
import { strict as assert } from 'node:assert';

assert.deepEqual(NaN, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(NaN))) // => false
assert.deepEqual(Infinity, JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(Infinity))) // => false
```